# Why didn't Obito revive Rin by Rinne Rebirth jutsu?

Tags: naruto

As we all know, Obito choose the path to use Infinite Tsukuyomi for creating a lovely dream in which his crush Rin & Kakashi are alive, but he could use Rinne Rebirth jutsu to revive Rin.

So, why did Obito choose the path to cast Infinite Dream & why couldn't he revive Rin by Rinne Rebirth jutsu?

Answer (score 5):

The Infinite Tsukuyomi was not all about Rin. Rin dying was the main trigger for him to change sides, but not the only reason.

He says that while he travelled under the identity of Madara through the world, he saw how bad things were and that's why he decided to move even more forward with the Tsukuyomi plan. 
Obito meant to help the world itself, even if it sounds ironic or even dumb.

[image]

As he says, Rin is someone who isn't meant to die, what caused her to die at that young age, alongside many children sent to war, was the current state of the shinobi world, just like he says

> The shinobi system... the village... what's created all these circumstances...

Therefore, he realized things had to change and he went forward with the Tsukuyomi plan.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common misconception about Obito's character throughout the Naruto Fandom and beyond.

Obito didn't start the 4th Great Ninja War or strive to complete the Eye of the Moon Plan because Rin was killed, but because Rin being killed was endemic of a larger problem and that was the Shinobi World itself. From the very start, we see just how ruthless and cutthroat the Shinobi World can be, the fact that the Chuunin Exams held by the Hidden Leaf Village, the tamest of all the Elemental Nations, still had numerous Shinobi die shows just how twisted the world of Naruto can be.

And Obito isn't the only person to come to this sort of conclusion, Nagato did as well. He saw how corrupt the world was and sought to enforce his own version of peace where there would be one, over-arching figure-head so powerful, it would deter anyone from starting a war in fear of being wiped off the face of the planet. Obito wanted to create a world where everyone could live out their ideal fantasies without having to shed blood. And of course, for Obito, his ideal fantasy was being with Rin because, honestly, she was the first person to ever show him any sort of real kindness outside of a handful of people. Not to mention, Obito, much like Naruto, tended to get attached to his teammates, and would do anything to keep them alive/happy.